# Getting 400 error while trying to fetch data from nginx docker, frontend is in reactjs and backend is in Spring boot also using Spring Cloud gateway

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, nginx-config

I have setup my whole backend in docker which is working fine while I am running frontend from npm (not in docker).
Now, I am trying to use it using nginx docker but I am getting 400 error at every GET request to the backend.

Here is nginx.conf file

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

# error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  <ip>;

        #charset koi8-r;

        access_log  access.log;
        error_log error.log;

        location /eprimo {
            root   "/usr/share/nginx/html";
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://<ip>;
    }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    
client_max_body_size 100M;

}}
```

while in access logs I am getting

> 

upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: , server: , request: "GET /user_service/api/getuserroles HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http:///user_service/api/getuserroles", host: "localhost:3000", referrer: "http://localhost:3000/eprimo/"

> 

I have tried multiple headers but still suggest me some of the most important headers which must be in this configuration file.

Also I am using only nginx.conf file present in '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' not using '/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' here but I have tried with that also response was same.

Let me know if any more information is required.
Please suggest me any solution every relevant solution is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: you are not providing an upstream server: `"http:///user_service/api/getuserroles", host: "localhost:3000"`. You nginx and application containers need to be on the same nerwork and in nginx.conf you need to declare the `proxy_pass` as `http://<app_container_name>:<app_container_port>`

Comment: ok I'll try this out.. but I have tried same configuration in nginx which is not running in docker and that is working perfectly